# Won't let me open regedit

Tags: windows-vista, windows-registry, memory-leaks

I was going to try to access `regedit` to try out [Indrek's answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/412484/windows-key-shortcuts-stopped-working), because i wanted to do the option one [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/82994-drive-letter-add-change-remove-windows.html) (couldn't open flag+r), because when I try to access the disk management from the control panel to change the drive letter it looks like this and won't load:

[image: Screenshot 1]

When i try to run `regedit.exe` I get
(rough translation): ***regedit.exe - invalid dump*** ulib.dll isn't meant to be run on Windows or it had an error. Try to install the software again or contact admin bla bla

[image: Screenshot 2]

I've been having constant memory leaks/problems these days like crashing to blue screen. My computer has frozen 3 times already today before I post this. During those freezes I started getting a pop up every time i booted my computer that something wanted to run, but it didn't have an assigned software for it, so I ran it in dev c++ and got this: 851k lines of errors. the cpp file is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/2cgxknyfsaye82e/error.rar). I couldn't upload it to pastebin or put on quotes because of the length.

I have Windows Vista 32-bit, 3.00GHz Duo, 4GB RAM and Nvidia 9800gtx+

Comment: run **sfc /scannow** from a cmd, started as admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the cpp file and saw the following lines at the beginning involving terms about Minecraft:
--27 achievements
--195 recipes
--Setting user: Brother\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\Diagnostic.log,

All the errors are java related about files not being found. I don't understand java but just looking at the file path being referenced I can see there's an issue.

Let's take one file path: C:\Users\Dear Brother\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\stats\stats_brother\appdata\roaming.minecraft\diagnostic.log_unsent.tmp (Määritettyä polkua ei löydy).

Can you see how the Appdata\roaming.minecraft is repeated twice in that file path. That shouldn't be: it should be just once.

As a test, you could suspend or remove java from your machine and take your testing from there. Maybe that will help with the other issues. Hope that helps and good luck.